# Стираются пробелы в конце строки при написании макроса VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Писал на vba макросы в модуле к файлу. В один прекрасный момент на новой строке любое слово подсвечивается красным (предыдущий код ок работает, любое добавление кода в него мучительно).

Стираются пробелы - как только ставишь пробел и хочешь начать писать 2-е слово, пробел стирается. Гугл нашел только [подобную проблему](http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=8&TID=27663), которая осталась без решения. Все ок только при включенном design mode. Может здесь кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой же проблемой ?

Comment: А если переустановить офис?
И на всякий случай советую проверить региональные настройки на наличие чего-нибудь странного.

Comment: @Qwertiy это будет уж совсем крайний вариант) все-таки хочется обойтись без переустановки, на работе это муторно - через заявки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, такой проблемой уже задавались на [**enSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164138/vba-editor-auto-deletes-spaces-at-the-ends-of-lines). Было предоставлено несколько решений проблем:

В окне написания кода VBA нажать на *Tools* -> *Options* -> снять галку с "*Auto Syntax Check*"

---

Второе решение - убрать один из Add-in'ов, которые пришли вместе с Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

1. Нажать на иконку Excel, перейти в "Параметры" (или Файл -> Параметры)
2. перейти во вкладку "Надстройки"
3. Выбрать надстройки COM и перейти туда
4. Найти надстройку 'Load Test Report AddIn' и снять галку с него
5. Перезапустить Excel

Данное решение лучше тем, что остаётся автопроверка написанного кода.

---

Мне помогло собственное решение. Где-то говорили, что такой баг происходит при добавлении на лист MS WebBrowser компоненты, что, собственно, и было у меня. Поэтому я в режиме Конструктора удалил WebBrowser компоненту и, выйдя из режима Конструктора, вернуть браузер с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.